# Restrict name of uploaded file

Tags: php, file-upload, restriction

I am using the following code for user to upload an image.

```
if ((($_FILES["companylogofile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["companylogofile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["companylogofile"]["size"] < 75000))
  {
  if ($_FILES["companylogofile"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["companylogofile"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("Template/" . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["companylogofile"]["tmp_name"],
      "Template/" . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"]);
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
```

As you can see I only accept .jpeg files to be upload with a restriction on size.  What I also need to do is add a restriction to the name of the file they are upload.  Basically I want to only allow files to be uploaded if they are named say: Logo.  Is there a way to put a restriction on the name of the files being uploaded?

Thanks!

Comment: can't you just add an additional check for $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"] at the top like you are doing for the various other parts of the FILE array?

Comment: Billy you can rename the uploaded file in the process when moving the temp file of the upload to it's destination. For example always rename to logo.jpg if that is the only valid filename.

Comment: "Template/" . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"]); I've changed that to: "Template/" . $_FILES["companylogofile"]["Logo.jpg"]); Is that what you are talking about hakre?

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!preg_match("/logo/i", $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"])) die("File have to contain 'logo' in name");
```

if you're looking exactly for "Logo.jpg", it is achievable by

```
if ("Logo.jpg" != $_FILES["companylogofile"]["name"]) die("File have to contain 'logo' in name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is definitely a way to put a restriction on string formats. I would recommend you look into using PERL regular expressions via PHP using preg_match http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

If you haven't used regular expressions before, they are simply a way to test against string formatting via a condensed syntax. A GREAT place to get started with regular expressions can be found here: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

What constitutes a 'bad' file" Logo3? logo-with-some-long-rambling-filename?

```
function isValidFileName($filename) {
   ... what do you want here?
}

if (!isValidFileName($_FILES['companylogoimage']['name'])) {
   die("Ooops, bad filename");
}
```

Just FYI: Don't use the `['type']` value in the $_FILES array for validation. That's the mime-type of the file as provided by the user - it can be easily changed to lie to you. Use something like [`getimagesize()`](http://php.net/getimagesize) to make the server determine the image's type.

Comment: Yes, anything besides just plain Logo, is a bad filename.

Comment: `if ($_FILES['companylogoimage']['name'] != 'Logo') { ... bad image ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just test `$_FILES['companylogofile']['name']`. Example:

```
if (false === strpos(strtolower($_FILES['companylogofile']['name']), 'logo')) {
    echo 'Error!';
    unlink($_FILES['companylogofile']['tmp_name'];
    return;
}
```

But, why would you want to put such an annoying restriction on the upload? I hope you're not thinking it will make it ore secure or anything?

Comment: upload tempfiles are automatically removed at the end of the request. no need to unlink two times.